# presentModalViewController in iOS6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

In my app's code I am still presenting viewcontrollers modally with presentModalViewController. This is deprecated in iOS 6. Does that mean this method has no effect on devices running iOS 6?

If yes, how can I make my app present viewcontrollers modally on iOS 6? My Xcode version does not support iOS 6, so all new methods in iOS 6 are unavailable to me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Deprecated means that you shouldn't use this method anymore. It still works, but it might be completely removed in one of the next updates.

For displaying view controllers modally, you can use the new `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` method introduced in iOS 5.0.
For dismissing the new method is `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Comment: I think the dismiss is `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.

Comment: i have tried to change `self.viewController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES`  to `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` not working guide me please

Comment: `-presentModalViewController:animated` should be replaced by `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Answer (score 42):

**If you have**

```
[self presentModalViewController:aController animated:YES];
```

**change it to**

```
[self presentViewController:aController animated:YES completion:nil];
```