# Should I use pushViewController or presentModalViewController for iPad UIModalPresentationFormSheet?

Tags: ios, ipad, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

In all the examples of UIModalPresentationFormSheet, presentModalViewController is used. However, according to documentation, presentModalViewController has been deprecated in iOS 6.0. But I do not see any examples where UIModalPresentationFormSheet is shown with pushViewController.

Which one should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [presentModalViewController in iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746407/presentmodalviewcontroller-in-ios6)

Comment: Look at the docs for `presentModalViewController:`. It shows you what to use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, set your controller's presentationStyle

```
 controllerToBePresented.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Then

```
[self presentViewController:controllerToBePresented animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```